# Confusion regarding the Working mechanism of Activation function

Tags: neural-network, classification, svm, activation-function, self-study

For binary classification irrespective of the model used, the sigmoid function is a good choice for output layer because the actual output value ‘Y’ is either 0 or 1 so it makes sense for predicted output value to be a number between 0 and 1.

My confusion is that is there a binary step function in the output layer which squashes the values of the linear combination of weights and and inputs to 0 or 1? Does classification means always applying a thresholding function on top of a linear or non-linear function which is in the hidden layer?

Say the predicted output value is 0.75 and actual Y is 0. Then, how is 0.75 converted to 1? The loss function would calculate the error as actual - predicted = 0-0.75 = -0.75

Can somebody please explain the math or point out some links where the working steps are shown? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think following picture by *Rubens Zimbres* can express how this process will be done except loss function part:
[image: img]

> Is there a binary step function in the output layer which squashes the values of the linear combination of weights and and inputs to 0 or 1?

Answer : Yes if you consider following example shows how Sigmoid squishes values to be between 0 and 1:
[image: img]

> Does classification means always applying a thresholding function on top of a linear or non-linear function which is in the hidden layer?

Answer: It does.

> Say the predicted output value is 0.75 and actual Y is 0. Then, how is 0.75 converted to 1? The loss function would calculate the error as actual - predicted = 0-0.75 = -0.75

Answer: Loss function and calculation of error for classification-based NN is **not** just by computation of  $Y_Actual - Y_prediction$

but It is used normally by combination of [Softmax activation function](https://deepnotes.io/softmax-crossentropy) and [cross-entropy](https://towardsdatascience.com/understanding-binary-cross-entropy-log-loss-a-visual-explanation-a3ac6025181a) as follow:
[image: img]

See the whole training process Multinomial Logistic Classification $D(S(wx+b),L)$
[image: img]

Comment: Awesome! thank you for the illustration and point wise explanation.

Comment: One last question -- why do we need sigmoid and not just a binary threshold function for the last output layer in classification to 0 and 1?